# Parsing data from mongodb to javascript array object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello i'm learning mongodb and nodejs. i was successful in retrieving all collections of an order. Below is the output

```
The orders: { __v: 0,
  nonmeat: 'pineapple',
  meat: 'Bacon',
  sauce: 'AlfredoSauce',
  crust: 'medium',
  _id: 571c1b9aed52d5e5462b99f9 },{ __v: 0,
  nonmeat: 'pineapple',
  meat: 'Bacon',
  sauce: 'AlfredoSauce',
  crust: 'medium',
  _id: 571c1bba07f035e646d24aa8 },{ __v: 0,
  nonmeat: 'parmesan,olives',
  meat: 'Salami',
  sauce: 'MarinaraSauce',
  crust: 'large',
  _id: 571c1e3c28dd30ed469eb6df },{ __v: 0,
  nonmeat: 'parmesan,olives',
  meat: 'Salami',
  sauce: 'MarinaraSauce',
  crust: 'large',
  _id: 571c1f11ba02d9f646f4c5c0 }
```

But i want to convert this to a javascript array cause the collection returns an array of objects. I want to filter out `__v` and `_id`. I intend to use this result to be displayed on google pie chart. I just want the key items: `nonmeat`, `meat`, `sauce` and `crust`. I intend to display a percentage of the items on google pie chart.

Below is my code retreiving the data from mongodb:

```
app.get('/orders', function(req, res){

    var allorders = [];
    //get all orders
    PizzaOrder.find({}, function(err, orders){

        if(err) throw err;

         console.log('The orders '+orders.length);

         //this is wrong
         for(var i=0; i<orders.length;i++) {
            allorders.push(JSON.parse(orders[i]));
         }
    });
    console.log('Orders retrieved '+ allorders);

    res.json(allorders);

});
```

**UPDATE!!!!!!!!**

I was able to send it in json and view on the browser. This is my code:

```
app.get('/orders', function(req, res){
    //get all orders
    PizzaOrder.find({}, function(err, orders){

        if(err) throw err;

         console.log('The orders '+orders.length);
         res.send(orders);
    });
});
```

But i want to filter it out the `_id:` and `__v:`. I'm using ajax call to receive the response and intend to display on google pie chart.

Comment: Which Mongodb API are you using

Comment: i used mongoose and mongolab

Comment: Not the accepted anwer in the duplicate, but the one that shows `.toObject()`, since you need to do that for objects you can manipulate. But excluding fields in projection works just as well.

Comment: @BlakesSeven please could u show an example

Comment: @user3497437 please provide what is the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to remove _id and __v simply do:

```
 for(var i=0; i<orders.length;i++) {
    delete orders[i].__v;
    delete orders[i]._id;
    allorders.push(orders[i]);
 }
```

Comment: that did not work as i attempted it

Comment: You know there is a great big warning issued when adding a "new answer" when you already have submitted one. You really should pay attention to that.

Answer (score 0):

try without JSON.parse

```
     //try this
     for(var i=0; i<orders.length;i++) {
        allorders.push(orders[i]);
     }
```

Comment: i updated my question. As i was able to send a json and view on browser but i wanter to filter out the `_id` and `__v` and use the items to display in google pie chart